# Filter Logs in Android programmatically

Tags: android, logging

This is method to fetch and dump logs in SDCard for Android. This is working fine, but I am wondering if we can put filter to trace logs related to specific tags.

I tried `logcat -s *TagIWant;` but it didn't work. Any other suggestion?

```
public static void Log(Context context){
    String filename = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + File.separator + "my_app.log";
    String command = "logcat -d *:V";

    Log.d(TAG, "command: " + command);

    try{
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {               
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("XXX", 0);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (patternu != null
                    && !pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
                continue;
            }
            log.append(line);
            log.append('\n');
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Android29 - Thanks, you mean to say "XXX" is the TAG i can look for ?

Comment: Android28 - Nop it didn't work. It is still giving complete logs

Comment: Any other suggestion from other candidates

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter the line that you want to write like the code below:

```
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("The String you want to exist in your log")){
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            }
            else{continue;}
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace "Your_Tag" with your tag, that will give you the logs with tag as specified in  with priority "Debug" and Above.

```
String command = "logcat Your_Tag:D *:S";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Check more on http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html